# When and how to tell colleagues that your's wife is pregnant?

Tags: colleagues, health

One of my coworkers does not come to work this week. We only know from the manager that his wife is going to deliver soon. Clearly he chose not to divulge the surprise to anyone other than the manager. I know that the pregnancy is purely private information. I wonder if there is a social norm on when and how to break the news about a pregnancy to your coworkers.

Comment: Don't blame him for not telling you. Women who worry about possible miscarriages generally want the news of their pregnancy to reach the least number people possible. Miscarriages are far more common than most people think. As a husband, he probably has a good idea of how his wife feels about telling others the news and he's probably just following her wishes.

Comment: What anyone does outside work is their own business. It is their choice if they want to tell their coworkers. Do you expect him to tell you each time he takes a vacation to attend a music concert, or goes out to eat icecream with his wife? Same story. Personally, I *prefer* coworkers not telling me their private stories. Life is short, I could do with one less **useless trivia**.

Answer (score 4):

As you correctly noted, it's purely private information. You're welcome to tell people whenever you feel like it or not at all. And as a coworker, you have no right to that information - stop worrying about it and get on with your job.

Comment: Actually , depending on how much time you are taking off, there are some coworkers who do need to know because they have to cover the work for you. At a minumum your manager does. It s not purely private information if others are affected by it.

Comment: @HLGEM they have to know that you will be away at given time, however, I don't think they should know the reasons as it hardly changes anything.

Comment: @HLGEM Only the manager needs to know. It is their job to figure out who has to cover for the absent employee, and they will let the concerned people know. There's no need for all the co-workers to know when the employee is pregnant.

Comment: +1 for "stop worrying about it and get on with your job."

Answer (score 3):

This of course depends greatly on whether you arepregnant or nonproegnant spouse.

You can't hide it forever if you are the one pregnant, but generally people do not admit to it until after the first trimester. Exact timing may also depend on the work needs. You might not want to mention it shortly before a huge deadline or other time of stress. You also might not want to mention it until people start asking you if there are rumors of a layoff.

You will want to tell your manager first at a few months months in advance because you are going to be taking more than a week off and he/she needs to do the planning for that.

If you are having health problems along with the prgenancy, you nmight need to disclose to management sooner especially if you might be put on bed rest. At this time you can talk about the possibility of working from home or taking a disability leave.

Use your judgement on when to tell, a long-time employee can admit to a pregnancy sooner than a recent hire (especially if you knew you were prgenant when you got hired). The recent hire might want to get a solid reputation for working well before bring it up as long as it is not physically obvious. If you have seen or heard about this employer (leagally or illegally) letting pregnant employees go, then of course you will not say anything until the last possible minute. If there are dangerous chemicals you can't be exposed to, you need to bring it up as soon as possible.

Coworkers can be told anytime after the manager is made aware. It is probably courteous to tell them at least by the 6-7th month.

For men or non-pregnant women with pregnant spouses, there is little need to tell anyone except the manager that they will be taking time of for this because men generally don't take that much time. If you are working in a place that offers paternity leave and you intend to take advantage of it, you will want to tell your boss somewhat in advance so planning around the absence can be handled (usually a copuple of months will do).

If your absence will be affecting others or project schedules, you may want to tell at least the people who will likely be directly affected by your absence before the event as a courtesy but it us not actually required. However, in most cases, people like to hear happy things and it is a way to connect with your co-workers.

If the pregnancy is not going well, it is best to keep quiet about it to everyone who is not a personal friend except your boss who needs to know you may need to leave on little notice just like when you have any other potential emergency pending.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, let the co-worker make the announcement on his own. It's his information and it's his information to disclose on his own terms, at the time, place and circumstance on his own choosing.

I would act as if nothing happened, but I'd probably be plotting with others to give that co-worker a free lunch when he gets back - if he gets back :)